# Como puedo eliminar las filas en blanco de un Archivo.txt con C#

Tags: c#

Mi Archivo.txt tiene esta forma y quiero eliminar las filas en blanco

> ```
> 10203040   F       B   B   B   B   B   A   A   X   A   C 
>
> 10209647   F       C   A   B   B   B   B   B   A   B   A 
>
> 10217686   F       B   B   A   A   A   A   B   B   X   B
>
> 10224729   M       B   A   A   X   B   C   A   A   A   X
> ```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: C#? php? cual es el problema? que intentaste?

Comment: lo que quiero es eliminar las filas vacías o en blanco de un arhivo.txt, algún método o función en c# asp.net, que me pudieras recomendar

Comment: Que intentaste o probaste? Que investigaste? Fijate q esta marcada como php. Si es c# usa el boton [edit] y pon el tag que corresponde. Si no demuestras q intentaste, lo mas probable es que tu pregunta se cierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas,
Podrias utilizar algo de LinQ para filtrarlas, te pongo un ejemplo

```
static void RemoveWhiteLines(string strSourcePath,string strDestinePath)
{
  //Lee todas las lineas del fichero
  string[] strAllLines = File.ReadAllLines(strSourcePath);
  //Selecciona las lineas que no sean null o blancas
  string[] strWritedLines = strAllLines.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray();
  //Guarda las nuevas lineas en el nuevo fichero
  File.WriteAllLines(strDestinePath, strWritedLines);
}
```

Podrias simplificarlo más tambien

```
static void RemoveWhiteLines(string strSourcePath,string strDestinePath)
{
  //Lee todas las lineas del fichero
  string[] strAllLines = File.ReadAllLines(strSourcePath);
  //Selecciona las lineas que no sean null o blancas
  //Guarda las nuevas lineas en el nuevo fichero
  File.WriteAllLines(strDestinePath, strAllLines.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray());
}
```

Lo que hace el programa es leer todas las lineas del path que le indicas, borrar las lineas en blanco, y guardarlas en el otro fichero que le indicas, pero podrias retornarlas, o lo que te interese

Atte